# div with the id="(name)" can I use this or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Can I use id with `"("` and `")"` in jquery mobile ?

for example:

```
<div id="RSI(3,4)">
</div>
```

I have tried that id and want to access that element in js.

```
$("#RSI(3,4)").html("some text");
```

but it didn't worked.

Comment: Escape the special chars \\\(... \\\) http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the special chars

```
$("#RSI\\(3\\,4\\)").html("some text");
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

That said, about the validity of using special characters in an ID, some validators would complain and I do certainly NOT recommend using any special chars in an ID nor use leading digits just because you can according to the latest html specs. Make your life easier and use only a-zA-Z0-9 and if needed, underscore

Comment: Very interesting, did not know this! Do you know if there are limitations on the use of this? e.g. incompatible browsers etc?

Comment: @BenM There shouldn't be any cross-browser compatibility issues, since jQuery's goal is to be browser-agnostic. If any exist, it's probably a jQuery bug.

Comment: Only validators should complain and I do certainly NOT recommend using any special chars in an ID nor use leading digits just because you can according to the latest html specs. Use a-zA-Z and if needed, underscore

Comment: not working this code

Comment: uesd this $("#RSI\\(3\\,4\\)").html("some text");

Comment: Thanks - I updated my answer. Missed the comma

Answer (score 1):

W3C Validator says that this html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="RSI(3,4)"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

is valid for html5 but not for html4.01 Strict, for which `(` is invalid character in `id` attribute.
http://validator.w3.org/check

In jQuery you have to escape them with `\\`

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

can you please check this  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/erdwF/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#RSI\\(3\\,4\\)").html("some text");
});
```

**Working Fine**

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the comma needed to be escaped too